# Проблема с SendMail на Centos - обрабатывает только часть запросов

Tags: linux, limits

В логах такое:
/usr/sbin/sendmail: error while loading shared libraries: libwrap.so.0: cannot open shared object file: Error 23

Как лечится, кто знает?

Comment: Это вроде просто лимит на количество открытых файлов из файловой системы. Там что-то их слишком ретиво открывает. Посмотрите открытые файлы через `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr` и убейте процесс который открывает много файлов `lsof` и `ps -ef`.

Comment: Спасибо. А не знаете, где этот лимит регулируется и как?

Comment: `sysctl -w fs.file-max=666666` либо `ulimit -n 65536` если нужно для шелла текущего юзера поменять. Чтобы при следующей перезагрузке сработало `echo "fs.file-max=786046" > /etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: Спасибо большое, igumnov! Помог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 23 означает что в системе [исчерпан лимит на количество открытых файлов в ядре](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h).

[Например в errno.h для ядра версии 2.6 есть такая строчка](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h?h=linux-2.6.39.y):

```
#define ENFILE      23  /* File table overflow */
```

#### Извлечь информацию о лимите.

Просмотреть число открытых файлов обычным способом:

`cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr`

или эвристикой:

`lsof | wc`

`ps -ef | wc`

Просмотреть разрешенный максимум:

`cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`

[Список открытых файлов](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?lsof+8):

`lsof`

#### Установить свой лимит.

`sysctl -w fs.file-max=666666`

или

`echo 666666 > /proc/sys/fs/file-max`

Сохранить лимит при перезагрузке (добавив строку в `/etc/sysctl.conf`):

`echo "fs.file-max=666666" >> /etc/sysctl.conf`

Через [ulimit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ulimit.3.html):

`ulimit -n 65536`

Сохранить лимит при перезагрузке для текущего пользователя (добавив строку в `~/.bashrc`):

`echo "ulimit -n 65536" >> ~/.bashrc`

Через [/etc/security/limits.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf):

Для всех пользователей жесткий 512, добавить туда строчку вида:

```
*               hard    nofile          512
```

Comment: Поправьте, пожалуйста, в примерах записи в sysctl.conf и .bashrc с `>` на `>>`.

Comment: Да, да пропустил ночью пока писал, это важно, спасибо за правку.